# Media player that can play files from online sources (like YouTube, SoundCloud, etc.)

Tags: media-player

I need a media player that does just one thing:  Play a file and take for example either a YouTube or a Spotify or a SoundCloud or a Mixcloud URL and play it.

So, a media player that is based on playing via APIs from other storages than local, but possibly also play local files.

I have tried all media players and none can take a YouTube URL and play it.

Comment: For which operating system? Is support for some of the online services required (if yes, for which?), or would you also be happy for a player that only supports one of them?

Comment: Not MacOS. I'd be happy for a "gnutube" that does one thing and does it well for example `gnutube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFe6-kj3g-I` should play the media and only the media. I'd also be happy with audio only but I want the program "gnuish" and minimal.

Comment: You could try [Baka-MPlayer](http://bakamplayer.u8sand.net/index.php)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for one, then you have to try [VLC Media Player](http://videolan.org/). Even the YouTube URL also worked in it.

Comment: Gagan, could you please at least include a link to where to find the player? Usually I'd ask also to list how it matches the requirements, but the question doesn't give much of that ;) Pointer: Our [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). Thanks! // PS: The downvote isn't mine ;)

Comment: [VLC Media player](http://videolan.org), click to that link

Comment: Thanks, [edit]ed that into your answer.